# How is a function resolved at runtime?

Tags: linux

How does a function resolve in Linux at runtime? Is it purely based on the name and and some "symbol table" as I've imagined, or is it a hardcoded address of some sort? I read online that you have to recompile for Musl libc, and for glibc, yet shouldn't they have the same symbol exports? How do symbols work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the program is loaded into memory before run time, functions map to certain memory addresses, relative to the base address. All calls to a function are compiled as the relevant memory address. The symbol table is often included in a binary, but to reverse address mappings to human-readable names for debugging purposes. Try `nm -D /usr/lib/libc.so.6` on a typical Linux installation to see glibc's symbol table.

In terms of binary compatibility, glibc and Musl both implement shared standards, but there are a variety of idiosyncrasies that must be reflected in their own header files (hence why there isn't a univeral package of standard library headers in most Linux distros - they're bundled with each library instead).

From musl's FAQ:

> **Is musl compatible with glibc?**
>
> Yes and no. At both the source and binary level, musl aims for a degree of feature-compatibility, but not bug-compatibility, with
>   glibc. When applications that work with glibc fail to compile against
>   musl, the cause will usually be one of the following:
>
> - Assuming that including one header will cause symbols from another unrelated header to be exposed. This is an application bug,
>     and fixing it is as simple as adding the missing #include directives.
> - Using implementation details from the glibc headers which were not meant to be exposed to applications. This is also an application
>     bug, and it can usually be fixed by search-and-replace (e.g. replacing
>     __pid_t with pid_t in the source).
> - Use of an interface that’s not implemented in musl. This can only be fixed by making the application’s use of the interface
>     optional, or by extending musl to support the missing interface.
>
> Binary compatibility is much more limited, but it will steadily increase with new versions of musl. At present, some glibc-linked
>   shared libraries can be loaded with musl, but all but the simplest
>   glibc-linked applications will fail if musl is dropped-in in place of
>   /lib/ld-linux.so.2.